# Chapter 7 of ruby on rails tutorial 4 sass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am having an issue when going through chapter 7 of the 4th edition of ruby on rails tutorial.

The error message is as follows:

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Undefined variable: "$state-danger-text".
Extracted source (around line #15):
13
14
15
16

    .form-control {
        color: $state-danger-text;
    }
}

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace
```

My custom.css.scss is as follows:

```
/* forms */

#error_explanation {
    color: red;
    ul {
        color: red;
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    }
}

.field_with_errors {
    @extend .has-error;
    .form-control {
        color: $state-danger-text;
    }
}
```

Everything up to this point ran just fine and I had also tried to copy and paste the code above directly to test for typos.  Bootstrap-sass is also loaded.  Unfortunately, that didn't resolve the issue.  For reference, the chapter I'm working off of can be found [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up).  Thank you.

Comment: The error seems quite clear to me:  `Undefined variable: "$state-danger-text"`.  What do you think you should do if you have an undefined variable?

Comment: right.  Sorry, I should've included my guess as to what the issue was.  The variable is not explicitly defined in the instructions, so my guess is that the variable being referenced is related to something defined within bootstrap and is addressed with "@extend .has-error".  That is, unless I missed the instruction where $state-danger-text IS indeed supposed to be defined by me.  A ctrl+f for "$state-danger-text" has unfortunately yielded nothing and suggests otherwise.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. In short, I had not included `@import 'bootstrap';`. But in the context of the tutorial, all of the [s]css was meant to be included on custom.css.scss, but I had actually entered all of it in application.scss and just started to type the portion I had included above in custom.css.scss, thereby leaving out `@import 'bootstrap';` and not having access to `$state-danger-text`.